# Class or interface expected - Provider name

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to declare my content provider class in the manifest but it shows me an error when I type the name of the fully qualified name of the provider class:

The error is Class or Interface expected, what does that mean?

the error was at this line: android:name="com.sns.awesomecharactercreator.CharacterProvider" There is a red line underit and when I hover over it says class or interface expected

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--suppress ALL -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sns.awesomecharactercreator" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Welcome"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EditingCharacter"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_general_characteristics"
        android:parentActivityName=".Notes" >
    </activity>

    <provider
            android:authorities="com.sns.awesomecharactercreator.characterprovider"
        android:name="com.sns.awesomecharactercreator.CharacterProvider"
        android:exported="false" />
</application>
```

CharacterProvider class:

```
package com.sns.awesomecharactercreator;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;

import DATALAYER.DBHelper;


public class CharacterProvider extends android.content.ContentProvider {

private final static String AUTHORITY =         "com.sns.awesomecharactercreator.characterprovider";
private final static String BASE_PATH = "characterattributes";
public final static Uri CONTENT_URI =
        Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + BASE_PATH);

private static final int CHARACTERS = 1;
private static final int CHARACTERS_ID = 2;

private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher =
        new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

static {
    uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH, CHARACTERS);
    uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH + "/#", CHARACTERS_ID);
}

private static final String[] allColumns = {
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_ID,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_NAME,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_MEANING,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_NICKNAME,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_RELIGION,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_BIRTHDATE,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_BIRTHPLACE,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_SIGN,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_TALENTS,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_MAINSEC,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_WEAPONS,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_CLASSS,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_STRENGTHS,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_WEAKNESSES,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_ROLE,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_VOICE,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_SECRETS,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_PROFESSION,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_QUOTE,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_AGE,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_BODYTYPE,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_HEIGHT,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_WEIGHT,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_FACESHAPE,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_EYECOLOR,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_HAIRCOLOR,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_HAIRSTYLE,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_SPECIALFEATURES,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_HEALTH,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_DISABILITIES,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_SKINTONE,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_ACCESORIES,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_CLOTHES,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_ALOOKALIKE,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_ETHNICITY,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_IQLEVEL,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_EDUCATION,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_DOMINANTMOOD,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_MORALCODES,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_DESIRES,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_DISLIKES,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_ATTITUDES,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_EMOTIONHANDLING,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_QUALITIES,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_FLAWS,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_GOALS,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_POPULARITY,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_REPUTATION,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_CHARISMA,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_RELATIVES,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_COMPANIONS,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_LOVELIFE,
        DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_NOTES};


private SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {

    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper(getContext());
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    return db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_CHARACTERATTRIBUTES, allColumns, selection, null, null, null, null);


}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    long id = db.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_CHARACTERATTRIBUTES, null, values);
    return Uri.parse(BASE_PATH + "/#" + id);
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    return db.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_CHARACTERATTRIBUTES, selection, selectionArgs);
}

@Override`enter code here`
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    return db.update(DBHelper.TABLE_CHARACTERATTRIBUTES,values,selection,selectionArgs);
}
}
```

Could someone be a dear and help me here? I'm stuck for like forever and I'm nearly ripping my hair off.

Comment: You're missing key information: what line causes the error to be displayed? Show the full error message as well.

Comment: This is my best guess since you didn't show the full error. Try changing android:authorities="com.sns.awesomecharactercreator.characterprovider" to android:authorities="com.sns.awesomecharactercreator.CharacterProvider"

Comment: Ahh, so sorry, the error was at this line:

 android:name="com.sns.awesomecharactercreator.CharacterProvider"

There is a red line underit and when I hover over it says class or interface expected